Upgrade streamlit with Conda doesn't work
I'm trying to upgrade my streamlit version from 1.12.2 to its latest version. I followed the documentation like described here. First I activate my conda environment:
conda activate mariokart_app

After that I run the command like discussed in the documentation:
conda update -c conda-forge streamlit -y

Which returns:
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 24.5.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=24.5.0



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/quinten/opt/miniconda3/envs/mariokart_app

  added / updated specs:
    - streamlit


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    altair-5.3.0               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         427 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-auth-0.7.22          |       h26aba2d_2          91 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-cal-0.6.14           |       hb0e519c_1          38 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-common-0.9.19        |       hfdf4475_0         204 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-compression-0.2.18   |       hb0e519c_6          18 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-event-stream-0.4.2   |      hc5e814a_12          46 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-http-0.8.1           |      ha6e9f73_17         159 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-io-0.14.8            |       hf69683f_5         135 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-mqtt-0.10.4          |       h76e2169_4         136 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-s3-0.5.9             |       hd10324c_3          92 KB  conda-forge
    aws-c-sdkutils-0.1.16      |       hb0e519c_2          48 KB  conda-forge
    aws-checksums-0.1.18       |       hb0e519c_6          48 KB  conda-forge
    aws-crt-cpp-0.26.9         |       h473fab1_0         281 KB  conda-forge
    aws-sdk-cpp-1.11.329       |       h6b2b1af_3         3.3 MB  conda-forge
    blinker-1.8.2              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    brotli-python-1.1.0        |  py312heafc425_1         358 KB  conda-forge
    c-ares-1.28.1              |       h10d778d_0         149 KB  conda-forge
    ca-certificates-2024.6.2   |       h8857fd0_0         152 KB  conda-forge
    debugpy-1.8.1              |  py312hede676d_0         2.0 MB  conda-forge
    gitpython-3.1.43           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         153 KB  conda-forge
    idna-3.7                   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          51 KB  conda-forge
    importlib_resources-6.4.0  |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          32 KB  conda-forge
    ipython-8.25.0             |     pyh707e725_0         585 KB  conda-forge
    ipywidgets-8.1.3           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         111 KB  conda-forge
    jinja2-3.1.4               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         109 KB  conda-forge
    jsonschema-4.22.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          72 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_client-8.6.2       |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         104 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_core-5.7.2         |  py312hb401068_0          91 KB  conda-forge
    jupyterlab_widgets-3.0.11  |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         182 KB  conda-forge
    libabseil-20240116.2       | cxx17_hc1bcbd7_0         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    libarrow-16.1.0            |   h0870315_6_cpu         5.6 MB  conda-forge
    libarrow-acero-16.1.0      |   hf036a51_6_cpu         512 KB  conda-forge
    libarrow-dataset-16.1.0    |   hf036a51_6_cpu         506 KB  conda-forge
    libarrow-substrait-16.1.0  |   h85bc590_6_cpu         473 KB  conda-forge
    libblas-3.9.0              |22_osx64_openblas          14 KB  conda-forge
    libcblas-3.9.0             |22_osx64_openblas          14 KB  conda-forge
    libcurl-8.8.0              |       hf9fcc65_0         377 KB  conda-forge
    libcxx-17.0.6              |       h88467a6_0         1.2 MB  conda-forge
    libdeflate-1.20            |       h49d49c5_0          69 KB  conda-forge
    libexpat-2.6.2             |       h73e2aa4_0          68 KB  conda-forge
    libgoogle-cloud-2.24.0     |       h721cda5_0         834 KB  conda-forge
    libgoogle-cloud-storage-2.24.0|       ha1c69e0_0         512 KB  conda-forge
    libgrpc-1.62.2             |       h384b2fc_0         4.9 MB  conda-forge
    liblapack-3.9.0            |22_osx64_openblas          14 KB  conda-forge
    libopenblas-0.3.27         |openmp_hfef2a42_0         5.8 MB  conda-forge
    libparquet-16.1.0          |   h904a336_6_cpu         922 KB  conda-forge
    libsqlite-3.45.3           |       h92b6c6a_0         881 KB  conda-forge
    libtiff-4.6.0              |       h129831d_3         251 KB  conda-forge
    libwebp-base-1.4.0         |       h10d778d_0         347 KB  conda-forge
    libzlib-1.3.1              |       h87427d6_1          56 KB  conda-forge
    llvm-openmp-18.1.6         |       h15ab845_0         293 KB  conda-forge
    markupsafe-2.1.5           |  py312h41838bb_0          25 KB  conda-forge
    matplotlib-inline-0.1.7    |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    ncurses-6.5                |       h5846eda_0         804 KB  conda-forge
    numpy-1.26.4               |  py312he3a82b2_0         6.7 MB  conda-forge
    openssl-3.3.1              |       h87427d6_0         2.4 MB  conda-forge
    orc-2.0.1                  |       hf43e91b_1         429 KB  conda-forge
    packaging-24.0             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          49 KB  conda-forge
    pandas-2.2.2               |  py312h1171441_1        14.0 MB  conda-forge
    parso-0.8.4                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          73 KB  conda-forge
    pillow-10.3.0              |  py312h0c923fa_0        40.6 MB  conda-forge
    platformdirs-4.2.2         |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          20 KB  conda-forge
    prompt-toolkit-3.0.46      |     pyha770c72_0         264 KB  conda-forge
    protobuf-4.25.3            |  py312hf6c9040_0         362 KB  conda-forge
    psutil-5.9.8               |  py312h41838bb_0         484 KB  conda-forge
    pyarrow-16.1.0             |  py312hdce95a9_1          26 KB  conda-forge
    pyarrow-core-16.1.0        |py312he4e9a06_1_cpu         3.7 MB  conda-forge
    pygments-2.18.0            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         859 KB  conda-forge
    python-3.12.3              |h1411813_0_cpython        13.9 MB  conda-forge
    python_abi-3.12            |          4_cp312           6 KB  conda-forge
    pyyaml-6.0.1               |  py312h104f124_1         181 KB  conda-forge
    pyzmq-26.0.3               |  py312ha04878a_0         436 KB  conda-forge
    referencing-0.35.1         |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          41 KB  conda-forge
    requests-2.32.3            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          57 KB  conda-forge
    rpds-py-0.18.1             |  py312ha47ea1c_0         293 KB  conda-forge
    setuptools-70.0.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         472 KB  conda-forge
    snappy-1.2.0               |       h6dc393e_1          36 KB  conda-forge
    streamlit-1.35.0           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         6.6 MB  conda-forge
    tenacity-8.3.0             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          23 KB  conda-forge
    tornado-6.4                |  py312h41838bb_0         821 KB  conda-forge
    traitlets-5.14.3           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         108 KB  conda-forge
    typing-extensions-4.12.1   |       hd8ed1ab_0          10 KB  conda-forge
    typing_extensions-4.12.1   |     pyha770c72_0          39 KB  conda-forge
    tzlocal-5.2                |  py312hb401068_0          40 KB  conda-forge
    validators-0.28.3          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          36 KB  conda-forge
    watchdog-4.0.1             |  py312hbd25219_0         141 KB  conda-forge
    wheel-0.43.0               |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          57 KB  conda-forge
    widgetsnbextension-4.0.11  |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         1.0 MB  conda-forge
    zeromq-4.3.5               |       hde137ed_4         297 KB  conda-forge
    zstd-1.5.6                 |       h915ae27_0         487 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       129.4 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  appnope            conda-forge/noarch::appnope-0.1.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  asttokens          conda-forge/noarch::asttokens-2.4.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  comm               conda-forge/noarch::comm-0.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  debugpy            conda-forge/osx-64::debugpy-1.8.1-py312hede676d_0 
  decorator          conda-forge/noarch::decorator-5.1.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  exceptiongroup     conda-forge/noarch::exceptiongroup-1.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_2 
  executing          conda-forge/noarch::executing-2.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  importlib-metadata conda-forge/noarch::importlib-metadata-7.1.0-pyha770c72_0 
  importlib_metadata conda-forge/noarch::importlib_metadata-7.1.0-hd8ed1ab_0 
  importlib_resourc~ conda-forge/noarch::importlib_resources-6.4.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  ipykernel          conda-forge/noarch::ipykernel-6.29.3-pyh3cd1d5f_0 
  ipython            conda-forge/noarch::ipython-8.25.0-pyh707e725_0 
  ipywidgets         conda-forge/noarch::ipywidgets-8.1.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jedi               conda-forge/noarch::jedi-0.19.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jupyter_client     conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_client-8.6.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jupyter_core       conda-forge/osx-64::jupyter_core-5.7.2-py312hb401068_0 
  jupyterlab_widgets conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab_widgets-3.0.11-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  libabseil          conda-forge/osx-64::libabseil-20240116.2-cxx17_hc1bcbd7_0 
  libarrow           conda-forge/osx-64::libarrow-16.1.0-h0870315_6_cpu 
  libarrow-acero     conda-forge/osx-64::libarrow-acero-16.1.0-hf036a51_6_cpu 
  libarrow-dataset   conda-forge/osx-64::libarrow-dataset-16.1.0-hf036a51_6_cpu 
  libarrow-substrait conda-forge/osx-64::libarrow-substrait-16.1.0-h85bc590_6_cpu 
  libblas            conda-forge/osx-64::libblas-3.9.0-22_osx64_openblas 
  libcblas           conda-forge/osx-64::libcblas-3.9.0-22_osx64_openblas 
  libcrc32c          conda-forge/osx-64::libcrc32c-1.1.2-he49afe7_0 
  libexpat           conda-forge/osx-64::libexpat-2.6.2-h73e2aa4_0 
  libgfortran        conda-forge/osx-64::libgfortran-5.0.0-13_2_0_h97931a8_3 
  libgfortran5       conda-forge/osx-64::libgfortran5-13.2.0-h2873a65_3 
  libgoogle-cloud    conda-forge/osx-64::libgoogle-cloud-2.24.0-h721cda5_0 
  libgoogle-cloud-s~ conda-forge/osx-64::libgoogle-cloud-storage-2.24.0-ha1c69e0_0 
  libgrpc            conda-forge/osx-64::libgrpc-1.62.2-h384b2fc_0 
  libjpeg-turbo      conda-forge/osx-64::libjpeg-turbo-3.0.0-h0dc2134_1 
  liblapack          conda-forge/osx-64::liblapack-3.9.0-22_osx64_openblas 
  libopenblas        conda-forge/osx-64::libopenblas-0.3.27-openmp_hfef2a42_0 
  libparquet         conda-forge/osx-64::libparquet-16.1.0-h904a336_6_cpu 
  libre2-11          conda-forge/osx-64::libre2-11-2023.09.01-h81f5012_2 
  libsodium          conda-forge/osx-64::libsodium-1.0.18-hbcb3906_1 
  libsqlite          conda-forge/osx-64::libsqlite-3.45.3-h92b6c6a_0 
  libutf8proc        conda-forge/osx-64::libutf8proc-2.8.0-hb7f2c08_0 
  libxcb             conda-forge/osx-64::libxcb-1.15-hb7f2c08_0 
  libzlib            conda-forge/osx-64::libzlib-1.3.1-h87427d6_1 
  llvm-openmp        conda-forge/osx-64::llvm-openmp-18.1.6-h15ab845_0 
  matplotlib-inline  conda-forge/noarch::matplotlib-inline-0.1.7-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  nest-asyncio       conda-forge/noarch::nest-asyncio-1.6.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  parso              conda-forge/noarch::parso-0.8.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pexpect            conda-forge/noarch::pexpect-4.9.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pickleshare        conda-forge/noarch::pickleshare-0.7.5-py_1003 
  pkgutil-resolve-n~ conda-forge/noarch::pkgutil-resolve-name-1.3.10-pyhd8ed1ab_1 
  platformdirs       conda-forge/noarch::platformdirs-4.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  prompt-toolkit     conda-forge/noarch::prompt-toolkit-3.0.46-pyha770c72_0 
  psutil             conda-forge/osx-64::psutil-5.9.8-py312h41838bb_0 
  pthread-stubs      conda-forge/osx-64::pthread-stubs-0.4-hc929b4f_1001 
  ptyprocess         conda-forge/noarch::ptyprocess-0.7.0-pyhd3deb0d_0 
  pure_eval          conda-forge/noarch::pure_eval-0.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pyarrow-core       conda-forge/osx-64::pyarrow-core-16.1.0-py312he4e9a06_1_cpu 
  python_abi         conda-forge/osx-64::python_abi-3.12-4_cp312 
  pyyaml             conda-forge/osx-64::pyyaml-6.0.1-py312h104f124_1 
  pyzmq              conda-forge/osx-64::pyzmq-26.0.3-py312ha04878a_0 
  stack_data         conda-forge/noarch::stack_data-0.6.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  traitlets          conda-forge/noarch::traitlets-5.14.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  typing-extensions  conda-forge/noarch::typing-extensions-4.12.1-hd8ed1ab_0 
  tzlocal            conda-forge/osx-64::tzlocal-5.2-py312hb401068_0 
  validators         conda-forge/noarch::validators-0.28.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  watchdog           conda-forge/osx-64::watchdog-4.0.1-py312hbd25219_0 
  wcwidth            conda-forge/noarch::wcwidth-0.2.13-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  widgetsnbextension conda-forge/noarch::widgetsnbextension-4.0.11-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  xorg-libxau        conda-forge/osx-64::xorg-libxau-1.0.11-h0dc2134_0 
  xorg-libxdmcp      conda-forge/osx-64::xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3-h35c211d_0 
  yaml               conda-forge/osx-64::yaml-0.2.5-h0d85af4_2 
  zeromq             conda-forge/osx-64::zeromq-4.3.5-hde137ed_4 
  zipp               conda-forge/noarch::zipp-3.17.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  abseil-cpp-20230802.0-h61975a4_2
  arrow-cpp-14.0.2-h3ade35f_1
  blas-1.0-mkl
  boost-cpp-1.82.0-ha357a0b_2
  bottleneck-1.3.7-py312h32608ca_0
  brotli-1.0.9-h6c40b1e_8
  brotli-bin-1.0.9-h6c40b1e_8
  expat-2.6.2-hcec6c5f_0
  grpc-cpp-1.48.2-hbe2b35a_4
  gtest-1.14.0-ha357a0b_1
  icu-73.1-hcec6c5f_0
  intel-openmp-2023.1.0-ha357a0b_43548
  jpeg-9e-h6c40b1e_1
  libboost-1.82.0-hf53b9f2_2
  libiconv-1.16-h6c40b1e_3
  mkl-2023.1.0-h8e150cf_43560
  mkl-service-2.4.0-py312h6c40b1e_1
  mkl_fft-1.3.8-py312h6c40b1e_0
  mkl_random-1.2.4-py312ha357a0b_0
  numexpr-2.8.7-py312hac873b0_0
  numpy-base-1.26.4-py312h6f81483_0
  sqlite-3.45.3-h6c40b1e_0
  tbb-2021.8.0-ha357a0b_0
  utf8proc-2.6.1-h6c40b1e_1
  zlib-1.2.13-h4b97444_1

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  altair             pkgs/main/osx-64::altair-5.0.1-py312h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::altair-5.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  attrs              pkgs/main/osx-64::attrs-23.1.0-py312h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::attrs-23.2.0-pyh71513ae_0 
  aws-c-auth         pkgs/main::aws-c-auth-0.6.19-h6c40b1e~ --> conda-forge::aws-c-auth-0.7.22-h26aba2d_2 
  aws-c-cal          pkgs/main::aws-c-cal-0.5.20-h3333b6a_0 --> conda-forge::aws-c-cal-0.6.14-hb0e519c_1 
  aws-c-common       pkgs/main::aws-c-common-0.8.5-h6c40b1~ --> conda-forge::aws-c-common-0.9.19-hfdf4475_0 
  aws-c-compression  pkgs/main::aws-c-compression-0.2.16-h~ --> conda-forge::aws-c-compression-0.2.18-hb0e519c_6 
  aws-c-event-stream pkgs/main::aws-c-event-stream-0.2.15-~ --> conda-forge::aws-c-event-stream-0.4.2-hc5e814a_12 
  aws-c-http         pkgs/main::aws-c-http-0.6.25-h6c40b1e~ --> conda-forge::aws-c-http-0.8.1-ha6e9f73_17 
  aws-c-io           pkgs/main::aws-c-io-0.13.10-h6c40b1e_0 --> conda-forge::aws-c-io-0.14.8-hf69683f_5 
  aws-c-mqtt         pkgs/main::aws-c-mqtt-0.7.13-h6c40b1e~ --> conda-forge::aws-c-mqtt-0.10.4-h76e2169_4 
  aws-c-s3            pkgs/main::aws-c-s3-0.1.51-h6c40b1e_0 --> conda-forge::aws-c-s3-0.5.9-hd10324c_3 
  aws-c-sdkutils     pkgs/main::aws-c-sdkutils-0.1.6-h6c40~ --> conda-forge::aws-c-sdkutils-0.1.16-hb0e519c_2 
  aws-checksums      pkgs/main::aws-checksums-0.1.13-h6c40~ --> conda-forge::aws-checksums-0.1.18-hb0e519c_6 
  aws-crt-cpp        pkgs/main::aws-crt-cpp-0.18.16-hcec6c~ --> conda-forge::aws-crt-cpp-0.26.9-h473fab1_0 
  aws-sdk-cpp        pkgs/main::aws-sdk-cpp-1.10.55-h61975~ --> conda-forge::aws-sdk-cpp-1.11.329-h6b2b1af_3 
  blinker            pkgs/main/osx-64::blinker-1.6.2-py312~ --> conda-forge/noarch::blinker-1.8.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  brotli-python      pkgs/main::brotli-python-1.0.9-py312h~ --> conda-forge::brotli-python-1.1.0-py312heafc425_1 
  c-ares                pkgs/main::c-ares-1.19.1-h6c40b1e_0 --> conda-forge::c-ares-1.28.1-h10d778d_0 
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2024.3.11-~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2024.6.2-h8857fd0_0 
  charset-normalizer pkgs/main::charset-normalizer-2.0.4-p~ --> conda-forge::charset-normalizer-3.3.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  freetype            pkgs/main::freetype-2.12.1-hd8bbffd_0 --> conda-forge::freetype-2.12.1-h60636b9_2 
  gflags                 pkgs/main::gflags-2.2.2-hcec6c5f_1 --> conda-forge::gflags-2.2.2-hb1e8313_1004 
  gitdb                 pkgs/main::gitdb-4.0.7-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::gitdb-4.0.11-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  gitpython          pkgs/main/osx-64::gitpython-3.1.37-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::gitpython-3.1.43-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  glog                     pkgs/main::glog-0.5.0-hcec6c5f_1 --> conda-forge::glog-0.7.0-h31b1b29_0 
  jsonschema         pkgs/main/osx-64::jsonschema-4.19.2-p~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jsonschema-4.22.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jsonschema-specif~ pkgs/main/osx-64::jsonschema-specific~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jsonschema-specifications-2023.12.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  krb5                    pkgs/main::krb5-1.20.1-h428f121_1 --> conda-forge::krb5-1.21.2-hb884880_0 
  lcms2                    pkgs/main::lcms2-2.12-hf1fd2bf_0 --> conda-forge::lcms2-2.16-ha2f27b4_0 
  lerc                       pkgs/main::lerc-3.0-he9d5cce_0 --> conda-forge::lerc-4.0.0-hb486fe8_0 
  libbrotlicommon    pkgs/main::libbrotlicommon-1.0.9-h6c4~ --> conda-forge::libbrotlicommon-1.1.0-h0dc2134_1 
  libbrotlidec       pkgs/main::libbrotlidec-1.0.9-h6c40b1~ --> conda-forge::libbrotlidec-1.1.0-h0dc2134_1 
  libbrotlienc       pkgs/main::libbrotlienc-1.0.9-h6c40b1~ --> conda-forge::libbrotlienc-1.1.0-h0dc2134_1 
  libcurl               pkgs/main::libcurl-8.7.1-hf20ceda_0 --> conda-forge::libcurl-8.8.0-hf9fcc65_0 
  libcxx                pkgs/main::libcxx-14.0.6-h9765a3e_0 --> conda-forge::libcxx-17.0.6-h88467a6_0 
  libdeflate          pkgs/main::libdeflate-1.17-hb664fd8_1 --> conda-forge::libdeflate-1.20-h49d49c5_0 
  libev                    pkgs/main::libev-4.33-h9ed2024_1 --> conda-forge::libev-4.33-h10d778d_2 
  libnghttp2         pkgs/main::libnghttp2-1.57.0-h9beae6a~ --> conda-forge::libnghttp2-1.58.0-h64cf6d3_1 
  libpng                pkgs/main::libpng-1.6.39-h6c40b1e_0 --> conda-forge::libpng-1.6.43-h92b6c6a_0 
  libprotobuf        pkgs/main::libprotobuf-3.20.3-hfff283~ --> conda-forge::libprotobuf-4.25.3-h4e4d658_0 
  libthrift          pkgs/main::libthrift-0.15.0-h70b4b81_2 --> conda-forge::libthrift-0.19.0-h064b379_1 
  libtiff               pkgs/main::libtiff-4.5.1-hcec6c5f_0 --> conda-forge::libtiff-4.6.0-h129831d_3 
  libwebp-base       pkgs/main::libwebp-base-1.3.2-h6c40b1~ --> conda-forge::libwebp-base-1.4.0-h10d778d_0 
  markdown-it-py     pkgs/main/osx-64::markdown-it-py-2.2.~ --> conda-forge/noarch::markdown-it-py-3.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  markupsafe         pkgs/main::markupsafe-2.1.3-py312h6c4~ --> conda-forge::markupsafe-2.1.5-py312h41838bb_0 
  mdurl              pkgs/main/osx-64::mdurl-0.1.0-py312he~ --> conda-forge/noarch::mdurl-0.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  ncurses                 pkgs/main::ncurses-6.4-hcec6c5f_0 --> conda-forge::ncurses-6.5-h5846eda_0 
  openjpeg             pkgs/main::openjpeg-2.4.0-h66ea3da_0 --> conda-forge::openjpeg-2.5.2-h7310d3a_0 
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-3.0.13-hca72f7f_2 --> conda-forge::openssl-3.3.1-h87427d6_0 
  orc                       pkgs/main::orc-1.7.4-h995b336_1 --> conda-forge::orc-2.0.1-hf43e91b_1 
  packaging          pkgs/main/osx-64::packaging-23.2-py31~ --> conda-forge/noarch::packaging-24.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pandas             pkgs/main::pandas-2.2.1-py312he282a81~ --> conda-forge::pandas-2.2.2-py312h1171441_1 
  protobuf           pkgs/main::protobuf-3.20.3-py312hcec6~ --> conda-forge::protobuf-4.25.3-py312hf6c9040_0 
  pyarrow            pkgs/main::pyarrow-14.0.2-py312h0b9b6~ --> conda-forge::pyarrow-16.1.0-py312hdce95a9_1 
  pygments           pkgs/main/osx-64::pygments-2.15.1-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pygments-2.18.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pysocks            pkgs/main/osx-64::pysocks-1.7.1-py312~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pysocks-1.7.1-pyha2e5f31_6 
  python-tzdata      pkgs/main::python-tzdata-2023.3-pyhd3~ --> conda-forge::python-tzdata-2024.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  re2                  pkgs/main::re2-2022.04.01-he9d5cce_0 --> conda-forge::re2-2023.09.01-hb168e87_2 
  readline               pkgs/main::readline-8.2-hca72f7f_0 --> conda-forge::readline-8.2-h9e318b2_1 
  referencing        pkgs/main/osx-64::referencing-0.30.2-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::referencing-0.35.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  requests           pkgs/main/osx-64::requests-2.32.2-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::requests-2.32.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  rich               pkgs/main/osx-64::rich-13.3.5-py312he~ --> conda-forge/noarch::rich-13.7.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  rpds-py            pkgs/main::rpds-py-0.10.6-py312hf2ad9~ --> conda-forge::rpds-py-0.18.1-py312ha47ea1c_0 
  setuptools         pkgs/main/osx-64::setuptools-69.5.1-p~ --> conda-forge/noarch::setuptools-70.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  smmap                 pkgs/main::smmap-4.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::smmap-5.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  snappy                pkgs/main::snappy-1.1.10-hcec6c5f_1 --> conda-forge::snappy-1.2.0-h6dc393e_1 
  streamlit          pkgs/main/osx-64::streamlit-1.32.0-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::streamlit-1.35.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  tenacity           pkgs/main/osx-64::tenacity-8.2.2-py31~ --> conda-forge/noarch::tenacity-8.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  toolz              pkgs/main/osx-64::toolz-0.12.0-py312h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::toolz-0.12.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  tornado            pkgs/main::tornado-6.3.3-py312h6c40b1~ --> conda-forge::tornado-6.4-py312h41838bb_0 
  typing_extensions  pkgs/main/osx-64::typing_extensions-4~ --> conda-forge/noarch::typing_extensions-4.12.1-pyha770c72_0 
  wheel              pkgs/main/osx-64::wheel-0.43.0-py312h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::wheel-0.43.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1 
  zstd                     pkgs/main::zstd-1.5.5-hc035e20_2 --> conda-forge::zstd-1.5.6-h915ae27_0 

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  bzip2                   pkgs/main::bzip2-1.0.8-h6c40b1e_6 --> conda-forge::bzip2-1.0.8-h10d778d_5 
  cachetools         pkgs/main/osx-64::cachetools-5.3.3-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::cachetools-5.3.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  certifi            pkgs/main/osx-64::certifi-2024.2.2-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2024.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  click              pkgs/main/osx-64::click-8.1.7-py312he~ --> conda-forge/noarch::click-8.1.7-unix_pyh707e725_0 
  idna               pkgs/main/osx-64::idna-3.7-py312hecd8~ --> conda-forge/noarch::idna-3.7-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jinja2             pkgs/main/osx-64::jinja2-3.1.4-py312h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jinja2-3.1.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  libedit            pkgs/main::libedit-3.1.20230828-h6c40~ --> conda-forge::libedit-3.1.20191231-h0678c8f_2 
  libevent            pkgs/main::libevent-2.1.12-h04015c4_1 --> conda-forge::libevent-2.1.12-ha90c15b_1 
  libffi                 pkgs/main::libffi-3.4.4-hecd8cb5_1 --> conda-forge::libffi-3.4.2-h0d85af4_5 
  libssh2              pkgs/main::libssh2-1.11.0-hf20ceda_0 --> conda-forge::libssh2-1.11.0-hd019ec5_0 
  lz4-c                   pkgs/main::lz4-c-1.9.4-hcec6c5f_1 --> conda-forge::lz4-c-1.9.4-hf0c8a7f_0 
  numpy              pkgs/main::numpy-1.26.4-py312hac873b0~ --> conda-forge::numpy-1.26.4-py312he3a82b2_0 
  pillow             pkgs/main::pillow-10.3.0-py312h6c40b1~ --> conda-forge::pillow-10.3.0-py312h0c923fa_0 
  pip                pkgs/main/osx-64::pip-24.0-py312hecd8~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pip-24.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pydeck             pkgs/main/osx-64::pydeck-0.8.0-py312h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pydeck-0.8.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  python                pkgs/main::python-3.12.3-hd58486a_1 --> conda-forge::python-3.12.3-h1411813_0_cpython 
  python-dateutil    pkgs/main/osx-64::python-dateutil-2.9~ --> conda-forge/noarch::python-dateutil-2.9.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pytz               pkgs/main/osx-64::pytz-2024.1-py312he~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pytz-2024.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  six                    pkgs/main::six-1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1 --> conda-forge::six-1.16.0-pyh6c4a22f_0 
  tk                        pkgs/main::tk-8.6.14-h4d00af3_0 --> conda-forge::tk-8.6.13-h1abcd95_1 
  toml                  pkgs/main::toml-0.10.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::toml-0.10.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  tzdata                 pkgs/main::tzdata-2024a-h04d1e81_0 --> conda-forge::tzdata-2024a-h0c530f3_0 
  urllib3            pkgs/main/osx-64::urllib3-2.2.1-py312~ --> conda-forge/noarch::urllib3-2.2.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  xz                         pkgs/main::xz-5.4.6-h6c40b1e_1 --> conda-forge::xz-5.2.6-h775f41a_0 



Downloading and Extracting Packages
                                                                                                                              
Preparing transaction: done                                                                                                   
Verifying transaction: done                                                                                                   
Executing transaction: done 

Finally I check the version with:
streamlit version
Streamlit, version 1.12.2

Which as you can see stays the same. I don't know why this happens so I was wondering if anyone knows how to upgrade your streamlit using Conda?

Make sure you have the correct environment activated by running which streamlit

Hi @foglerit, Thanks for your comment! This returns: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/streamlit. So how do I change this?

It looks like your conda environment might not be activated. Try to activate it again and check if your Python interpreter is being picked up from it with which python

@foglerit, Unfortunately, the streamlit version stays the same.
